# Change the continuous animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a form and have attached some animation of `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` with it. A button when clicked toggle the display of forms. But when I continuously click on the button it just makes the animation run almost without a stop.

For more clearance, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/FRvyn/).

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var delay = 500;
    $(document.body).on('click',"#sign_up_btn",function (e) {
//      $("#sign_in").hide("slow");
//      $("#sign_up").show("slow");
        $("#sign_in").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#sign_up").delay(delay).fadeIn("slow");
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
        $(this).attr("value", "Already have an account?");
        $(this).attr("id", "sign_in_btn");
        $(this).fadeIn("slow");

    });
    $(document.body).on('click',"#sign_in_btn",function (e) {
//        $("#sign_up").hide("slow");
//        $("#sign_in").show("slow");
        $("#sign_up").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#sign_in").delay(delay).fadeIn("slow");
        $(this).fadeOut("slow");
        $(this).attr("value", "Create An Account");
        $(this).attr("id", "sign_up_btn");
        $(this).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

**Try clicking the big button a several times and see the result.**

How can I resolve that issue?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, try clicking that button a several times and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1.

You have an invalid `</input>` tag in your code.
<sub>(P.Suggestion: Avoid using `tables` wherever you can. Makes difficult to read your HTML markup and style your elements.)</sub>

## 2.

That's cause you don't use `.stop()` before performing a new `fade`

Also, you should use the `fade In/Out` animations callback before starting a new animation. Your code should end up looking like this:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/igazak/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
var $sUp = $("#sign_up"),
    $sIn = $("#sign_in");

$("#content").on('click', "#sign_up_btn", function(){    
  
  $sIn.stop().fadeOut(800, function(){
    $sUp.fadeIn(800);
  });      
  $(this).stop().fadeOut(800, function(){
     $(this).attr({value:"Already have an account?", id:"sign_in_btn"}).fadeIn(800);                    
  });
  
}).on('click', "#sign_in_btn", function(){
  
  $sUp.stop().fadeOut(800, function(){
     $sIn.fadeIn(800);
  });      
  $(this).stop().fadeOut(800, function() {
    $(this).attr({value:"Create An Account", id: "sign_up_btn"}).fadeIn(800);              
  });

});
```

Comment: It didn't helped, try clicking the big button a several time and see what's happening